# HTML5 chinese chess board and pieces

Tags: html

I have a project about chinese chess.
First I have to create a board and about 32 chessman on board .
Should I using 1 canvas to create board then draw 32 images on it OR create 1 board canvas then create 32 canvas , each for 1 chessman . Because I want to drag and drop chessmans but it seem not well when I have to redraw too much if just use 1 canvas. What should I do , can u give me some advices or give me some same tutorial . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

KineticJS is a Javascript library that will help you out. It supports dragging of things on canvases, etc. Here's a simple tutorial using Kinetic and an HTML5 canvas: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/

Comment: i'm checking on it , ty . Is it possible to create a image as background , then another images drag on it (keeping background) ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a matter of preference, so take it with a grain of salt.  I would only use one canvas and draw the pieces directly onto it.

In most games (HTML 5 included), the rendering is all pretty "smoke and mirrors", and the real data is stored in ugly structures behind the scenes.  Trying to use multiple canvases pulls some of that data (specifically location) and mess into the rendering layer.  While this can probably still work, you'll have more control over whats happening if you keep *all* the data behind the scenes, and use math to determine where to render and whether or not a mouse click has hit an object and you need to start dragging.

Comment: I implemented 1 canvas , and draw image on it . I redraw a chessman (draw board at current position then draw new position of chessman) but when drag fast it's not smooth as expect. I wonder , should I redraw all chessman or just 1 .

Comment: If you're only handling 32 images, it should be fine to redraw them all every frame.

Comment: yeah , but i have to redraw board ,too . And it makes screen blink .. Any solution to keep board's background and just redraw chessman ?

Comment: The canvas is transparent, so you can set the background image to be your board if you'd like.  If you are getting flickering, make sure all your draws are done together.  You might also need to call Window.requestAnimationFrame() to make sure you draw before the window is repainted.